# How to schedule a worker to run every x hours in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have created a Heroku free account and deployed a Node JS application through a web dyno.

Besides that, I would like to know whether a Heroku free account would allow me to schedule another dyno to execute another Node JS project which simply writes Hello World in the console every 2 hours. Is that possible? Where can I find documentation on how to do schedule a worker and run a Node JS application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) is what you are looking for.
This will spin up one-off dynos at whatever schedule you define, to run whatever task you define for it.
Provided you do not exceed your account's free dyno-hours allocation between your web dyno and your one-off dynos, you will be able to do this completely for free.

Comment: Hi! Does it work? I'm trying to schedule every day a process which takes about 5-10min to complete. Right now I put my script in bin folder and it's starting but stops after a while... Don't know if I have to specify a worker for that... If I do, do I have to schedule it manually (without heroku scheduler)? I don't think it will run because with the free plan, my instance will sleep after 30min. Not so clear how I can achieve this!